# Is there a graph with these properties?3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Is there a way to make a graph with these properties:

$i)$ $17$ vertices so that every vertex has a degree of $3$ and

$ii)$ $27$ vertices split into two columns where the first column has $10$ vertices each of them with a degree of $3$ and the second column has $17$ vertices each of them with a degree of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the sum of degrees is two times the number of edges. So it has to be even and the answer to (i) should be immediate.

In the second case, I assume that the graph is meant to to be bipartite. Then the sum of degrees of vertices on the left should equal the sum of degrees of vertices on the right...